# Python - Jupyter Notebook: "Trusted Notebook" option grey out

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to enable the Trust_Notebook feature, so I could use variables in a markdown cell. However, the `Trusted Notebook` option is always grey out.

[image]

I have already did:

```
!sudo pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

and

```
!jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

What else did I miss for enable trusted notebook? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notebook is already trusted.  Here is the [security protocol for notebooks](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/security.html).

> When a notebook is opened by a user, the server computes a signature
>   with the user’s key, and compares it with the signature stored in the
>   notebook’s metadata. If the signature matches, HTML and Javascript
>   output in the notebook will be trusted at load, otherwise it will be
>   untrusted.

As for evaluating Python variables in markdown, try using the [Python Markdown Extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/wiki/python-markdown).  Here is a [simple way to install extensions](http://blog.rtwilson.com/an-easy-way-to-install-jupyter-notebook-extensions/comment-page-1/) for Jupyter.

Comment: But I still can not load a variable in a markdown cell using {{a}}. I thought it should work if the Notebook is trusted?

Comment: Do you mean loading a python variable in a markdown cell?

Comment: Yes. If the python variable is "a", loading "a" from a markdown cell using {{a}}

Comment: You need to load the [Python Markdown Extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/wiki/python-markdown).  This available in you nbextensons tab on your dashboard.  Then restart the notebook.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how where do I find my dashboard? Thanks!

Comment: When you start up jupyter, you should see tabs "Files", "Running", "Clusers", "Conda", "Nbextensions" provided you have installed the latest version on Anaconda.  Are any of these tabs missing?

Comment: The Notebook is on a server, all I am given is a link to use it: http://1.2.3.4:8888/notebooks/  to use. Is it possible to access the dash board based on the link information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130632/discussion-between-pylang-and-edamame).

Answer (score 0):

The Notebook dashboard
When you first start the notebook server, your browser will open to ***the notebook dashboard.*** The dashboard serves as a home page for the notebook. Its main purpose is to display the notebooks and files in the current directory. For example, here is a screenshot of the dashboard page for the examples directory in the IPython repository:

The above is from the following url
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3.x/examples/Notebook/Notebook%20Basics.ipynb